# java.sql.SQLException:Access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql

I have MySQL database "database" in my web. I want to connect it remotly from java. But I get Exception.

I use this code to connect it.

```
try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://site.ir:3306/database", username", "password");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = ("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    if(rs.next()) { 
        int id = rs.getInt("id"); 
        String str1 = rs.getString("imei");
        System.out.print(id+"+++"+str1);        
    }

    con.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think there's no problem in my code and username has All permission to access database! Please say what's problem!

Comment: "_But I get Exception._" Care to tell us which one that would be? Also which line it occurs on? Also, not sure if typo or not, but `username` has only 1 `"`.

Comment: In Line 4: Connection co......

Comment: And what is the exact exception?

Comment: Did you fix the `"` typo?

Comment: @Tiny You shouldn't add parts to OP's code which might actually be the source of the problem e.g. the `"` you added.